# Exclude specific words in Powershell Password Generator

Tags: powershell

I've created a script to create random passwords in the same format as Microsoft use in O365 when resetting a password.  If the randomly generated password contains any of the specified values which may potentialy offend then I want the script to ignore them and re-run the loop.

I've tried using -contains and -like statements but the output still contains some of those values.

```
write-host "Enter number of passwords you require generating" - 
ForegroundColor Green
$Run = read-host
foreach($i in 1..$Run)
 {
    If($i=$Run){                           
    $result = ""
    $set1 = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".ToCharArray()
    $set2 = "aeiou".ToCharArray()
    $result += $set1 | Get-Random
    $result += $set2 | Get-Random
    $result += $set1 | Get-Random

$DisabledPass=$result.Substring(0,1).ToUpper(1)+$result.Substring(1,2)+(Get-Random -Minimum 10000 -Maximum 99999)

$valuesToLookFor = @(
'*Sex*',
'*Bum*',
'*Cow*',
'*Fuc*',
'*Wog*',
'*Cum*',
'*God*',
'*Gob*',
'*Fuk*')

if ($DisabledPass -contains $valuesToLookFor) {continue}
$disabledpass |Out-File c:\admin\passwords.csv -Append
Write-Host "$DisabledPass" -ForegroundColor Green
}
 }
```

The script runs successfully but the output contains passwords that contain values that I want to ignore.

Comment: Try `$valuesToLookFor = 'Sex|Bum|Cow|Fuc|Wog|Cum|God|Gob|Fuk'; if ($DisabledPass -match $valuesToLookFor) {continue}`

Comment: I see a nice way to avoid foul language detection on SO... [grin]. Also, I gave up on generating my own passwords and instead use the DinoPass API :)

Comment: Not sure if this is the final way you intend to use this, but the way you have it set up to use `continue` to skip the 'bad' password means you won't end up with the requested number of passwords if any have forbidden words in them.  You probably want to use a different techniques such as keeping a count of the number of 'good' passwords generated and only stop when it reaches the required number.

Comment: Hooray for DinoPass..... I enjoy handing that out to adults and their API allows me to make a small cmdlet to call very easy.

Comment: remove "x" from set1 and "o"+"u" from set2, all done.

Comment: Thanks @Theo that works but as suggested if I want 100 passwords and 3 get rejected then I only have 97 passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$set1 = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".ToCharArray()
$set2 = "aeiou".ToCharArray()
$badWords = "(Sex|Bum|Cow|Fuc|Wog|Cum|God|Gob|Fuk)"

$count = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter number of passwords you require generating"

1..$count | ForEach-Object {
    do
    {
        $result = ""
        $result += $set1 | Get-Random
        $result += $set2 | Get-Random
        $result += $set1 | Get-Random

        $password = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($result) + (Get-Random -Minimum 10000 -Maximum 99999)
    } while ($password -match $badWords)

    Write-Host "Generated password: $password" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: When using RegEx anyway, a tad shorter `$badWords = "(Sex|[BC]um|Cow|Fu[ck]|Wog|Go[bd])"`